# Load On Demand for Comments [Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I'm trying to load comments for my website like Twitter.

I found some plugins that make this, but none of them worked for me.

I tried [This](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dnspinger/) , [this](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) & [this](http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/).

But the first one uses ASP, the second uses PHP, the third is very slow.

Isn't there anyone that loads comments continuously & is fast ? If you use such plugins, which one do you prefer, & do you know a better one ?

Thanks.